# Implement Google Voice Actions in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, google-voice

How can I implement the fairly new `Voice Actions` from Google, in Android?
I'm thinking about the possibility to listen to the `Listen to` action as used by some music application.
Is there a specific broadcast my app must register as a receiver to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explained in [Android Developers Blog: Supporting the new music Voice Action](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/09/supporting-new-music-voice-action.html):

> In your `AndroidManifest.xml`, just register one of your activities for the new intent `android.media.action.MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH`.… When your activity receives this intent, you can find the user’s search query inside the [`SearchManager.QUERY`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/SearchManager.html#QUERY) string extra.